# Save subset from List into Object

Tags: c#, list, algorithm, subset

I get from SAP a list with a lot of structures ( [index][structures with items]. My program used a subset from this items. I search for a solution to save this subset of items in a object with public setter and getter. I a kind of mapping

**First idea**

I can create a big switch an save each items in my specials object but I think this isn't a good idea.

**Second idea**

The properties names is equals the names from the list. I get all public setter and getter with this:

```
PropertyInfo[] prop = typeof(my object).getProperties()
```

Now I check the `prop.Name.Equals(item.name)` and saved it.

The problem is, my Object has then unreachable properties.

Comment: Can you share an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `switch` can be a good idea if you know exactly what properties you want and don't want. This enables easy unit testing and ensures that you program structures are hard coded - this is a good thing!

Another approach would be to use a simple `Dictionary`:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// ...

if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey("Property from SAP"))
{
    myDictionary.Add("Property from SAP", String.Empty);
}

// ...

myDictionary["Property from SAP"] = "Value from SAP";
```